# Permission denied to create files on root of C: Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a few Windows Server 2008 R2 servers that are denying the domain admins accounts permission to create files on the root of the C: drive. I have checked effective permissions on the C: drive and the local administrators group (which includes the domain admin accounts) have full control.

We are able to create files on our desktop and drag and drop them onto the root of C:, however we do receive an warning stating:

"You'll need to provide administrator permission to move to this folder"

Is there some new sort of security configuration that would introduce this behaviour in Server 2008 R2 or am I missing something?

Thanks for the help,

Jamie

Answer (score 4):

This is UAC blocking you from putting files there.  Windows 2008 and up considers a few places it's space.  The root of the disks is one of them.  You can disable UAC, but a better choice would be to put the files somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This is blocked by windows UAC. Run Disable UAC in system configuraion utility.